# How can I convert float to int in extJs controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, extjs, extjs4

I have ASP.NET MVC application with ExtJs4 client side code. I'm new in ExtJs4. I have next code:

```
columns: [
    {
        text: 'Money',
        width: 150,
        sortable: false,
        dataIndex: 'Money'
    }
```

This code return value = 0000.00, because Money is a float variable but I need value = 0000. May I with some interactions convert float to int inside my rendered block without changing my Model?

Comment: When you say change your model, do you mean on the client or server?

Comment: On the client. I don't need to change my model. Because it's used in another parts of my project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a column renderer:

```
{
    dataIndex: 'Money',
    renderer: Ext.util.Format.numberRenderer('0000')
}
```

Docs: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.util.Format-method-numberRenderer

Comment: Thank you, your solution is perfect, but I'm use just number.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a renderer function:

```
{
    text: 'Money',
    width: 150,
    sortable: false,
    dataIndex: 'Money',
    renderer: function(value, metaData, record, rowIndex, colIndex, store) {
        return Ext.util.Format.currency(value, '', 0);
    }
}
```

But if you want simple int value, you may:

```
    renderer: function(value) {return ~~value;}
```

Comment: No I need only integer format like: 00000, without any ',' or '$'

Comment: But you are on right way, I'm just replace your format into return Ext.util.Format.number(value, "0000");

Comment: If you want a simple INT, then you'd better use simple ~~value conversion!